# How to find 2 dynamically created div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I need to dynamically create 2 div in separate locations.
The first location is where you see the information, and second is where you edit information, and I want with delete to delete both divs with the same class.

I can't use the closest parent because they are placed in different locations in dom.

```
<div class="cart">

<div class="top-section"></div>
<div class="bottom-section"></div>

<input type="button" class="add_btn" value="Add fields" />
</div>
```

```javascript
/*This is how i add fields*/
let id = 0;
let something = 'Some info inside';
id++;
$('.add_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.top-section').append('<div class ="wrapper_section_'+id+'"><span>'+something+'</span><div class="delete">X</div></div>');
    $('.bottom-section').append('<div class="wrapper_section_'+id+'"><span>'+something+'</span></div>');
});

/*And with this i only delete wrapper-in-header class*/
$(.cart).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    $(.some_div).trigger('change');
});
```

How I can delete both divs at the same time?

Please check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnL9wugo/

```
/*And the issue what i currently have if i call .closest it give me undefined*/
$(.cart).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  var className = $(this).parent('div').parent().attr('class');
   $(this).closest('.cart').find('.bottom-section').children(className ).remove();
    x--;
});
```

Comment: are you creating the pair of divs multiple times?

Comment: How does `.some_div` relate to the appended `div` elements? It would help to see a more complete example

Comment: Can you add some minimal reproducible example with html showing the relative positions of all elements in question?

Comment: give them (all) a class without the ID then target only the ones you need `$(this).closest(".wrapper-in-header").find(".wrapper-section").delete()`.  If you provided a more complete example, this could be shown as an answer, but without that, it's speculation.

Comment: jsfiddle is incomplete - missing wrapper-in-header and delete button(s)

Comment: How do you create the delete button?  When you create that, give it `"data-id='"+id+"'"` then you know which wrapper_sections go with which delete button.

Answer (score 1):

Add same id to delete class div's data like this

```
<div class="delete" data-id="'+id+'">X</div>
```

you can find the div and remove now

```
var idDiv=$(this).data("id")
$(".wrapper_section_'+idDiv+").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the 2 divs an additional class, so you can identify them.

Like this:

```
$('.add_button').on('click', function(e) {
$('.wrapper-in-header').append('<div class="wrapper_section_'+id+' wrapper_section"></div><div class="delete">X</div>');
$('.wrapper-in-footer').append('<div class="wrapper_section_'+id+' wrapper_section"></div>');
});
```

And them delete them like this:

```
$('.some_div').on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    $('.wrapper_section').remove();
    x--;
    $(.some_div).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is it's delete everything with the class wrapper_section. I want to delete only div where is delete button called.

Answer (score -1):

@Danijel why not just use a very separate div class, or even ids?